# Nativescript - http.getFile() doesn't process error situations

Tags: nativescript

I'm using http.getFile() to download a file. Here's the code.

`httpModule.getFile( url, destPath ).then( function( result ) {}, function (error) {} );`

If I specify an invalid url (i.e. resulting in an http 404) - getFile() returns success result and the file contains the 404 html message. I would have thought a 404 (file-not-found) would result in a reject.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Status **404** es indication that you had a **successful** request made - and that the server has responded with non-existent content. You might want to implement logic to resolve different server statuses like 40x and 50x which are common scenarios and are caused not by error. in the HTTP request but by an error in the server side (missing content, fallen server, etc.).

In your reject fallback, you should expect to handle only unsuccessful requests resulting errors related to your code execution and should not handle logic based on the successfully returned HTTP status code. Those cases when you are catching an error, won't provide you any status code simply because the request has failed.

To handle logic based on status code you can use the following:

```
http.request({ url: "https://httpbin.org/get", method: "GET" }).then(response => {
        // Argument (response) is HttpResponse!
        var statusCode = response.statusCode;
        if (statusCode >== 400) {
            // do something to handle all statuses greater then 400
        }
    }).catch(err => {
    // handle execution errors here
})
```

Comment: I understand your point of view on the http.request(). Mine was an http get-file request. To eat up the error status/message (caused by whatever) and then return an incorrect file with no other status message/flags - am pretty sure is not an optimal way. Using your http.request() example - it's like there's no statusCode available. Now what? Anyway - AS ALWAYS - I appreciate your help.